# How to know which application creating the clnt_call stack.out files under /tmp directory in linux

Tags: linux

In my Linux system there are bulk of clnt_call stack.out files are creating under /tmp directory
Content in the files are like:

```
*** 2017/01/28 07:47:44.292 ***
    [00] 0x7f743e0377b9:0x7ffe4d1aac50 = sig_segv_term + 0x0049
    [01] 0x7f7441897370:0x7ffe4d1aacf0 = __restore_rt + 0x0000
    [02] 0x7f743ea66085:0x7ffe4d1b0e20 = timezone_get_system_default + 0x01f5
    [03] 0x7f743e033e31:0x7ffe4d1b0ec0 = clnt_driver_mgr_init + 0x0471
    [04] 0x7f7441894bb0:0x7ffe4d1b12f0 = pthread_once + 0x0050
    [05] 0x7f743e042432:0x7ffe4d1b1320 = cli_api_alloc_env + 0x0092
    [06] 0x7f743e04127a:0x7ffe4d1b1460 = cli_api_alloc_handle + 0x004a
    [07] 0x7f74412505f6:0x7ffe4d1b1470 = SQLAllocHandle + 0x0036
    [08] 0x52685a:0x7ffe4d1b14a0 = _Z9createEnvv + 0x001a
```

Can any one please help me, how to know which process is creating these files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lsof` command. Check the answers here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13776/how-to-determine-which-process-is-creating-a-file

If you don't have `lsof` command then you can trying reading `/proc/[PID]/fd` directory for all the processes.

```
/proc/PID/fd, a directory containing a symbolic link for each open file descriptor.
```

Ref : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs#Linux

Just dump content of all `fd` in a text file and search if it contains the file name you're looking for. If it does, the scroll up to find the PID.

To dump run `ls /proc/*/fd 2>/dev/null`